# Error Iterating Through Members of a Struct in Vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct and two vectors in my .h file:

```
struct FTerm {
    int m_delay;
    double m_weight;
};

std::vector<FTerm> m_xterms;
std::vector<FTerm> m_yterms;
```

I've already read in a file to populate values to m_xterms and m_yterms and I'm trying to iterate through those values:

```
vector<FTerm>::iterator terms;

        for (terms = m_xterms.begin(); terms < m_xterms.end(); terms++)
        {
            int delaylength = m_xterms->m_delay * 2; // Assume stereo
            double weight = m_xterms->m_weight;
        }
```

Although I'm pretty sure I have the logic wrong, I currently get the error Error expression must have a pointer type. Been stuck at this for a while, thanks.

Comment: you're not doing anything with `terms` inside the loop, is that intentional?

Comment: When you get errors like that, the error will include the line of code causing the error.  This is important!

Comment: `m_xterms` is not a pointer type

Comment: VTC: sorry but I don't see this question helping anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
int delaylength = m_xterms->m_delay * 2;
double weight = m_xterms->m_weight;
```

to

```
int delaylength = terms->m_delay * 2;
               // ^^^^^
double weight = terms->m_weight;
             // ^^^^^
```

as you want to access values through

```
vector<FTerm>::iterator terms;
```

within the loop

```
for (terms = m_xterms.begin(); terms < m_xterms.end(); terms++)
  // ^^^^^
```

---

> *"Although I'm pretty sure I have the logic wrong, ..."*

That can't be answered, unless you give more context about the requirements for the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the problem πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, your code *currently* has a problem that it simply doesn't accomplish anything except wasting some time.

Consider:

```
    for (terms = m_xterms.begin(); terms < m_xterms.end(); terms++)
    {
        int delaylength = m_xterms->m_delay * 2; // Assume stereo         
        double weight = m_xterms->m_weight;
    }
```

Both `delaylength` and `weight` are created upon entry to the block, and destroyed on exit--so we create a pair of values, then destroy them, and repeat for as many items as there are in the vector--but never do anything with the values we compute. They're just computed, then destroyed.

Assuming you fix that, I'd also write the code enough differently that this problem simply isn't likely to happen to start with. For example, let's assume you really wanted to modify each item in your array, instead of just computing something from it and throwing away the result. You could do that with code like this:

```
std::transform(m_xterms.begin(), m_xterms.end(),                // Source
    m_xterms.begin(),                                           // destination
    [](FTerm const &t) { return {t.m_delay * 2, t.m_weight}; });// computation
```

Now the code actually accomplishes something, *and* it seems a lot less likely that we'd end up accidentally writing it incorrectly.

Bottom line: standard algorithms are your friends. Unlike human friends, they love to be used.